# how to change android package name on phonegap build website

Tags: phonegap-build, phonegap, phonegap-pushplugin, phonegap-cli

i am trying to upload my apk on google play store but i am seeing this error: You need to use a different package name because com.phonegap.www is used by a pre-installed application. To upload a pre-installed application, please contact Google Play Developer Support. Learn more.
You need to use a different package name because "com.phonegap.www" already exists in Google Play. i just export my project as html from anyflip book as maker i didn't follow the phonegap normal build, please tell me how to change my package name[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ovqd.png)

Answer (score 0):

Change it in your config file before you upload anything.

Answer (score 0):

In the root folder you have a file called config.xml. The second line of that file starts with `<widget` and it has an attribute `id="com.phonegap.www"`. Change it to your own domain name for the app you're building, or to any value that should be globally unique. Then zip your folder, upload it to PhoneGap and try again.